# Multiplying strings

Tags: java, string, integer

If you have a string for example:

```
String = "Hello world";
```

How do you get it to print out (n) times?

For example

```
System.out.print("Hello world" * 5);
```

to give the output:

```
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
```

Now obviously I can't just multiply a string by 5, as I have done.

I know i have to convert the string into something an integer would be able to use? But how do I do this?

Comment: What number exactly would "Hello world" translate to?

Comment: Recursion also do the work check my answer

Answer (score 8):

You would use a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   System.out.println("Hello world");
}
```

But I think you need to work on your programming fundamentals here - a good book on java would be much more useful to you than posting questions like this on SO.

Answer (score 1):

In Python (Ruby too I think) you can very much concatenate string by "multiplying" it by number:

```
>>> print "Hello" * 5
HelloHelloHelloHelloHello
```

In Java specifically there is quite a number of ways to do it, beginning with loop. Incidentally you can concatenate strings multiple times in Java:

```
package test;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "hello";
    for (String s = s1; s.length() <= 5 * s1.length(); s = s + s1)
        System.out.println(s);
}

}
```

Now, above is a BAD IDEA. :-) If it is repeated, don't do it, bc every time you concatenate strings and assign a new one, a new string is created and old one is thrown away - very inefficient if you do it more than a few times.

In general, previous poster was right: pick a book about Java - better yet Python - and learn!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method that takes the string and the value for which the string needs to be printed like:

```
public String multiplyString(String s,int i){
   String result="";
   for(;i<0;i--){
       result += " "+result;   //for appending strings
   }
return result;
}
```

Then call this method:

```
System.out.print(multiplyString("Hello wrold",5));
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the method I need :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey learn bit on recursion method also

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    test("Hello World ",5);

}

public static void test(String s,int x){

      if(x==0)return;
          System.out.println(s);
      test(s,--x);

}
```

Out put

```
Hello World 
Hello World 
Hello World 
Hello World 
Hello World
```

Comment: Its not gonna make very much difference if you use `test(s,x--);`, however you can reduce just one line. But I think use of recursion will be expensive. Isn't it?

Comment: @smit Thanks but it should be test(s,--x)